# How to allow access to an Angular 8 app from outside the network? (the internet)

Tags: angular, ip, wifi

I've started the angular app with the ip I got from the WIFI connection:

[image]
    ng serve --host 192.168.1.102

Then I created entry in the TPLINK NAT forwarding--> virtual servers:

[image]

Lastly, I access from my mobile (outside internet) with the connection ip
I got from the ISP:

```
203.221.66.164:80
```

And the page is not loaded, any idea what I'm missing here ?

Comment: give your app app a public access
instid doing  `ng serve --host 192.168.1.102` -> `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`.
OR event better host your build via better http server [ apache, nginx, firebase, s3-bucket etc... ]

Comment: I;m starting now with >ng serve --host 0.0.0.0, what should I do next ?

Comment: simple, now you can access it on internet as i can do from here .
your web title is Moneysharing right ?

Comment: really? what is address you are using now?

Comment: http://203.221.66.164/

Comment: Without port? can you send the full url ?

Comment: browser use port 80 by default for http. Just enter ip address in your browser's address bar and done.

Comment: My mobile is not connected to the wifi and I tried to hit the address with no success

Comment: i added screenshot as answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196692/discussion-between-shivam-mishra-and-user2304483).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exposing the port to the world you just need to access it through public ip address.

yes that's true you build is not a production build so it will take a lot time to show result.

it took 6 minutes for me to load your website.

solution is include production build -> `ng serve --prod --host 0.0.0.0`.

[image]

make sure you know what you are doing, by opening a port to open world you are inviting security breach to your network which is insecure.